# Getting RestAssured test to work with Spring Security CSRF for AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, csrf-protection, rest-assured

I've found "[The Login Page: Angular JS and Spring Security](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii)" of great help, to add CSRF protection into a web application that uses Spring (Security, among others) implementing a REST API that's used by an AngularJS application. The AngularJS application uses form-based login (`JSESSIONID`) for authentication. Here's the essence of that work:

- Hidden input field `_csrf` on the login page
- `CsrfHeaderFilter` adds `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie to response
- `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` with `setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN")`

This **all does work fine** (as far as I can observe).

I believe this leads to the following flow:

1. Redirect to login page
2. Login page contains `_csrf`
3. Login response includes `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie
4. Angular uses cookie value as `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header on REST requests
5. Happiness!

Number 2. seems vanilla Spring Security CSRF. 3. and 4. seem [an attempt](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) to adapt to [AngularJS CSRF support](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Again, this **all does work fine**, from testing a staging instance. However, some **integration tests are broken**, specifically tests that are using RestAssured. I have not found good examples for RestAssured, of this set-up. [This](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#csrf) is all the documentation I can find.

It suggests using `formAuthConfig().withAutoDetectionOfCsrf()` or `withCsrfFieldName("_csrf")`, and doing an explicit `get` of the login page. Using this seems to be dealing **fine** with the login. But I don't understand how I then tell RestAssured to pivot to using the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header.

I've unsuccessfully gone through a lot of variations of this code, but I'm currently having this:

```
    FormAuthConfig baseConfig = new FormAuthConfig(loginPage, "username", "password");
    FormAuthConfig config = baseConfig.sendCsrfTokenAsHeader();
    config = config.withCsrfFieldName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    RestAssured.authentication = RestAssured.form(userName, password, config);

    given().auth().form("admin", "admin", baseConfig.withCsrfFieldName("_csrf"))
        .when().get(loginPage)
        .then().statusCode(200);

    expect().statusCode(200)
        .when().get(...); // line 246
```

This is awarded with the following output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /application_name/rest/something. Reason:
</p>
    <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
    <hr/>
    <i>
      <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
    </i>
    <hr/>
  </body>
</html>

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find the CSRF input field with name X-XSRF-TOKEN in response. Response was:
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /application_name/rest/something. Reason:
</p>
    <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
    <hr/>
    <i>
      <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
    </i>
    <hr/>
  </body>
</html>

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FormAuthFilter.filter(FormAuthFilter.groovy:85)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:49)
    at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeFilterChain(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:994)
<snip>
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.get(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at com.company.application_name.AbstractJettyJsonRestTest.getCollection(AbstractJettyJsonRestTest.java:246)
    at com.company.application_name.JsonRestIntegrationTest.testSomething(JsonRestIntegrationTest.java:74)
<snip>
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
```

Your help much appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to use RequestSpecification in RestAssured http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/2.4.1/com/jayway/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html

Comment: Thank you for that, but I'm afraid you're not appreciating that I'm a pretty experienced RestAssured user, who put in a lot of effort before asking this question, so just pointing me to the most core class (interface) in said library does not help me, unless I'm missing something here. In any case, a bit more elaboration would be of help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get csrf test working with RestAssured if you follow this pattern outlined on a google forum. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rest-assured/HidZCdNA4iA

Essentially you have to create a helper method to initiate the log in flow manually rather than relying on RestAssured to complete it for you. Here is the code required copied from it's original location to preserve it on SO.

```
protected SessionData login(String username, String password) {
    Response getLoginResponse =
        given().
            filter(sessionFilter).
        when().
            get("/login.html").
        then().
            extract().response();

    String token = getLoginResponse.header("XSRF-TOKEN");

    RestAssured.given().log().all().
        filter(sessionFilter)
        .header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken)
        .param("username", username)
        .param("password", password)
        .when()
        .post("/login");


    Response tokenResponse =
        given().log().all().
            filter(sessionFilter).
        when().

            get("/token").
        then().log().all().
            extract().response();

    return new SessionData(tokenResponse.header("XSRF-TOKEN"), sessionFilter.getSessionId());
}
```

The login method essentially navigates to the login page, gets the csrf token, uses that token to log in, then another call is made to get the updated sessionId and csrf token as they change after logging in.

Url and csrf parameters may need to change depending on your specific settings.

The SessionData is just a custom helper POJO to store the data in

```
private class SessionData {
    private String csrf;
    private String session;
}
```

This is then used in a test like this

```
@Test
public void whenAdminAccessDiscoveryResource_thenSuccess() {
    SessionData sessionData = login("admin", "admin");
    final Response response = RestAssured.given()
        .header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", sessionData.getCsrf())
        .filter(sessionFilter)
        .get(ROOT_URI + "/discovery");
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatusCode());
}
```

RestAssured assumes your sessionId is coming in a cookie labeled "JSESSIONID". If your sessionId has a different label you can change this by configuring RestAssured to look for that label.

```
    RestAssured.config = config()
        .sessionConfig(new SessionConfig().sessionIdName("SESSION"));
```

Replace "SESSION" with whatever your sessionId is labeled.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use header, Response res = given().header("X-Auth-Token",token).contentType("application/json")...... I had similar issue to pass X-Auth Token, it worked for me.